# Log4j2 doesn't find config file anymore

Tags: java, log4j2

In my project i set log4j up like this:

```
System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", new File("data/logconfig.xml").getAbsolutePath()); 
logger = LogManager.getRootLogger();
```

My Project folder looks like this:

```
My Project
|
|-src
|  |
|  |-many classes (including the one which includes the code above)
|  
|-data
|  |
|  |-logconfig.xml
|
|-lib
|-build
|-...
```

logconfig.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <RollingFile fileName="/Users/*****/Desktop/logs/logging.log" filePattern="/Users/*****/Desktop/logs/logging.log-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz" name="RollingFile">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ}; %p; %F:%L; [%t]; %m;%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 MB"/>
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20"/>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

log4j2, set up like this worked perfectly fine, until, triggered by something unknown to me, i always get "ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console."

I've already tried calling the Logfile by logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class);, renaming the file to "log4j2.xml" and copying it to src folder. But somehow nothing i tried brought it back to work again.

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: did you try put your `logconfig.xml` file into `resources` folder?

Comment: Don't do this. It makes a huge number of assumptions. If any code calls your logger before your code snippet is loaded, this **will fail** (as it has done). It may even fail randomly, if logging is called from `static` initialisers. If you ever find yourself calling `System.setProperty` **for any reason**. STOP.

Comment: Yeah but why doesn't the other method work?